# How to change .plist file for all translations?

Tags: python, ios, plist

In my iOS project we're using build script written in Python which sets keys in a .plist file.
What I tried is something like

```
plist_file = plistlib.readPlist("Project/Base.lproj/Info.plist")
plist_file['CFBundleDisplayName'] = app_name
plistlib.writePlist(plist_file, plist_path)
```

The problem is that only the base localisation of .plist will be changed.
Is there a way to change .plist file for all localisations at once or I should drop the idea of localised .plist file?

Comment: You need to modify your script to go over each localisation i.e. change `Base.lproj` to `en.lproj`, `de.lproj`, etc. There are probably multiple ways you could do that but the easiest would be to store an array of all the localisation keys you have in your project and then loop over that array.

Comment: You could accept as script parameter an array of languages and then you can scan those languages.